# Is it required to clear Native C++ memory while closing the C# App

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an C# application and it allocate memory and do the points conversion using C++ dll and every thing working fine. But is it required to clear the C++ native memory while closing application? my understanding is while closing the C# application it will take care of clearing the memory.

Comment: Please try to construct a minimal, verifiable, working example.

Comment: @TomdeGeus I disagree in this special case. You don't need code to ask this specific question.

Comment: Releasing memory explicitly is always a good practice, it's never a good idea to rely on OS / Framework do that for you

Comment: @JeromeReinländer then again the question might be off-topic as there is _no problem to solve_.

Comment: @MickyD Yes, you are right, there is no concrete problem... yet. But this question seems to be an attempt to prevent a problem in the future that might be very hard to detect. That's why I feel this is a valid question. Yes, it is also not too hard to find the answer yourself, but only if you know what you have to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually not *required* to clear the memory after closing your application. The OS will likely do that for you.
However: it is considered to be pretty dirty not do that, it might prevent you from detecting memory leaks through tools effectively and it also depends on the OS. The common OSs will clear your memory after the process ends, but I can not say anything about specialized OSs.

Short answer: clear your memory.

Comment: ok, i will clear C++ native memory explicitly using Dispose method